# SQL Server Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to customize my order by , if the Qty is negative then that row must be in fist then if the Qty is positive I will sort it by ExpDate

```
SELECT WhsCode,
       ItemCode,
       LotNumber,
       ExpDate,
       Qty
FROM rq_Test2
ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN qty < 0 THEN Qty
             ELSE ExpDate
         END
```

But I am getting an error of " Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. " .. Why ?

Thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have two case statements

```
Select 
      WhsCode,
      ItemCode,
      LotNumber,
      ExpDate,
      Qty 
from rq_Test2 
order by case when qty < 0 then Qty else null end ,
         case when qty > 0 then ExpDate else NULL end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select WhsCode,ItemCode,LotNumber,ExpDate,Qty 
from rq_Test2 
order by case when qty < 0 then Qty else ExpDate end
```

Here in `case` statement compiler will try to convert `Qty(numeric value)` to `Expdate(datetime)`

Because `case` statement will convert all `result_expression` to the data type with highest precedence in `result_expression`.

In your case `Datetime` has higher precedence than `numeric or int or Bigint etc..` So you are getting that error.

`SQL Server` uses the following `precedence` order for data types:

```
user-defined data types (highest)
sql_varian t
xml
datetimeoffset
datetime2
datetime
smalldatetime
date
time
float
real
decimal
money
smallmoney
bigint
int
smallint
tinyint
bit
ntext
text
image
timestamp
uniqueidentifier
nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
nchar
varchar (including varchar(max) )
char
varbinary (including varbinary(max) )
binary (lowest)
```

Comment: @Hans - Workaround around is already given by `Radar`. I just said why it is happening