# SQL Server Arithmetic Overflow Error - converting nvarchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sqldatatypes

I'm retrieving data from a view, and one of the columns I'm using is `nvarchar(50)`, but is only ever `N'True'` or `N'False'`, depending on the operation of a related date column in this parent view.

The following code retrieves the record ID and the column I'm looking for, `YTD`:

```
SELECT Enquiry_Number, YTD 
FROM dbo.vw_SalesPO_YTD
```

Output:

```
ENQ-001 True
ENQ-002 False
ENQ-003 True
```

However, I'm unable to filter my results using this `YTD` column for some reason. If I attempt to do this:

```
SELECT Enquiry_Number, YTD
FROM dbo.vw_SalesPO_YTD
WHERE YTD = N'True'
```

Then it fails with the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Which I don't understand because there are no `datetime` expressions in play in this query. Yes the `True` or `False` was determined by comparing datetimes in the parent view, but I don't understand how that might have trickled down to this subquery. Attempting the same thing in the parent view yields the same error - I'm demonstrating it this way for simplicity's sake.

However, performing a similar operation in the `SELECT` portion of the query works without issues:

```
SELECT 
    Enquiry_Number,
    YTD,
    CASE 
       WHEN YTD = N'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END As C
FROM
    dbo.vw_SalesPO_YTD
```

Output:

```
ENQ-001 True 1
ENQ-002 False 0
ENQ-003 True 1
```

However, these 1's and 0's inherit the same flaw, where I can't use them in a `WHERE` clause without getting this datetime error.

I've been searching hard and am not sure how to identify the core issue. I've been reading things about Collations and type precedence, but can't understand why this behaviour is happening.

When I've checked `YTD` in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, it confirms that this column is no different from other columns in my table: `YTD` is `nvarchar(50)`, using the `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation.

Related question: [SQL Server Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573774/sql-server-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-expression-to-data-type-datetime)

---

### The Source of the Problem

This issue is still unsolved, but if you wish to reproduce it, this code from the parent view must be generating this issue:

```
CASE WHEN 
Award_Date <= DATEFROMPARTS(FinancialYear - 1, 11, 1) + GETDATE() - DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(month, '20161101', GETDATE()) / 12, '20161101')
THEN N'True'
ELSE N'False'
END
```

Yes this looks overly complicated. We're checking the `Award_Date` against its associated `FinancialYear`, which runs from November 1st to October 31st. Each record already knows which `FinancialYear` it's in. The ultimate aim is to compare TODAY's position (2016-11-30) against TODAY last year (2015-11-30), and TODAY the year before (2014-11-30), etc.

So the code takes today's date and combines it with the `FinancialYear` for the associated record, and spits out whether the record had occurred between the start of its financial year and the **today** of the same year. And it's doing this successfully, but then I can't do anything with the `N'True'` or `N'False'` it's producing.

Comment: And what do you get if in your query in move the `WHERE` condition inside the inner select (i.e. `(SELECT Enquiry_Number, YTD FROM dbo.vw_SalesPO_YTD WHERE YTD = N'True')`) also, note that you are starting with `SELECT * FROM...` while it should be `SELECT A.* FROM...` (not sure this is related to your issue though).

Comment: Sanity check: does a `SELECT * FRMO dbo.vw_SalesPO_YTD` successfully complete? (Make sure you force all the rows to come back when testing.)

Comment: @FDavidov - thanks for that, I'd simplified the problem for putting on SE, but hadn't noticed I could cut it down to just the outer query! Have simplified in the Question, but it's still failing. Matt Gibson - yes, selecting all works fine, and I can filter (WHERE) by any column except **YTD**.

Comment: Did you try `WHERE YTD = 'True'`? (without the `N`)

Comment: @FDavidov - yes, that also fails with the same error, as does explicitly CONVERT'ing both sides of the WHERE clause to nvarchar(50)

Comment: If it's any help, the last code block in my question where I attempt to work around the issue by creating a new column called **C** does create 1's and 0's successfully using **YTD**, but inherits the same flaw where I can't actually use this new column in a **WHERE** clause without getting this 'converting expression to data type datetime' error. I've added this detail to the question.

Comment: I think that few years ago MS would pay users that find bugs in their critical software (SQL-Server would be one), so perhaps you are about to become (a little bit) richer... :-).

Comment: @FDavidov - I've added the source code which is probably causing the issue from the parent view, if you or anybody else wishes to try and reproduce.

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using & what's the compatibility level of the database? I'm unable to reproduce your error so far, but a compatibility level of 110 or above won't let you create a view with that query in it (date and datetime are incompatible in the add operator) .

Comment: @GarethLyons - we're using SQL Server Management Studio 2014, version 12.0.5000.0. The compatibility level is only 100 unfortunately...

Comment: Thanks, still unable to reproduce your error. Can you provide the full view query & base table datatypes? That case on it's own wouldn't result in a datatype of nvarchar(50) in the view so I guess there's more to it.

Comment: @GarethLyons Fortunately it's not really any more complex than what I've already posted, except I had enclosed that **CASE** in a **CONVERT(nvarchar(50), case when ... then ... else ... end)** for good measure, though the error happens with or without it. The View doesn't have to be any more complex than just selecting that CASE statement from the base table to get the error, and the Award_Date is a **datetime**, whilst FinancialYear is **int(4)**. I'm only working with 270 records, and none of them are in any way invalid or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a successful **workaround**, not a solution *per se* or explanation of the core issue.

There's obviously an issue with the data coming out of the view, which will not allow `YTD` column's results to be operated on in a `WHERE` clause, and yet they can be operated on by the time the query reaches its `SELECT` phase.

I've created a new `table` which explicitly defines the `YTD` column as `nvarchar(50)`, and then inserted all the records from my view into this table, which has resolved the issue. The records can then be sorted and filtered by `YTD` as they are supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what the type of the source YTD is.

Try using the following:

```
SELECT Enquiry_Number, [YTD] FROM (
    SELECT Enquiry_Number, CONVERT(nvarchar(10),YTD) AS [YTD] FROM dbo.vw_SalesPO_YTD
) AS A
WHERE A.YTD = N'True'
```

10 is just a thump suck value. It will cut of any part of the field longer that 10. It depends on your actual field size.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT Enquiry_Number, YTD 
     FROM dbo.vw_SalesPO_YTD) AS A
     WHERE cast(A.YTD as varchar) = 'True'`

Comment: Convert as varchar.  Don't into nvarchar

Comment: Don't convert as nvarchar

Comment: Till now, you didn't get any answer for this question?

Answer (score 1):

I used the following as an example:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
    Enquiry_Number nvarchar(10),
    YTD nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Data(Enquiry_Number, YTD)
SELECT N'ENQ-001', N'True' UNION
SELECT N'ENQ-002', N'False' UNION
SELECT N'ENQ-003', N'True' 


SELECT Enquiry_Number, [YTD] FROM (
    SELECT Enquiry_Number, CONVERT(nvarchar(10),YTD) AS [YTD] FROM @Data
) AS A
WHERE A.YTD = N'True'
```

Result:

```
ENQ-001 True
ENQ-003 True
```

There must be results in the YTD field that causes to return it as a datetime type.

Try a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_SalesPO_YTD WHERE ISDATE(YTD)= 1
```

Updated Question:
Try:

```
ISNULL(CASE WHEN  Award_Date <= DATEFROMPARTS(FinancialYear - 1, 11, 1) + GETDATE() - DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(month, '20161101', GETDATE()) / 12, '20161101') THEN N'True' ELSE N'False' END, 'false')
```

Comment: Thanks @Danie - your code runs successfully and produces the same unfiltered results as my original code, but I still get the same error when trying to filter by the column.

Comment: And for the record, the ISNULL's alternative result is never triggered in the results - all the records are showing the True or False, not the **false** the ISNULL would produce.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:- Don't add n before string

`SELECT * 
 FROM (SELECT Enquiry_Number, YTD 
     FROM dbo.vw_SalesPO_YTD) AS A
     WHERE A.YTD = 'True'`

Comment: Can you give me your date calculation in codings. That is the source of this problem

Comment: cast(cast(@yr_mnth_dt as char(8)) as datetime)

Comment: convert your date like this and then calculate.If it is not solve give me date calculation code